# Get Page Url in html.grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I  Have Link in a column of Html.grid in asp.net mvc application ,by clicking on that link ajax modal dialog popup is achieved ..while clicking on the link i want to pass url of page ....

how can i do it

Please help me

Regards
Manjunath

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could use HTML helpers inside a grid:

```
<%
Html.Grid<Person>(
    "people",
    column => {
        column.For(p => { %>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", new { id = p.ID }) %>
        <% });
        column.For(p => p.Name);
    }
);
%>
```